# Ubuntu Studio Installer authorization failed

Tags: software-installation, 22.04

When I attempt to use the Ubuntu Studio Installer in Ubuntu Studio 22.04 to install a package I selected, upon clicking on "Install selected packages" I get an error message box with message:

```
Authorization failed no packages installed
```

and then when "Okay" in that box is clicked on the Ubuntu Studio Installer closes.

Does this need to be run as root? My expectation is that it would open a window that asks for the root password, instead of this error message.

Another related problem:

Whenever I attempt to use Discover to install an application I get the error message "To few items to process". And then the application does not get installed. The applications I attempted to install were GIMP, Inkscape, and Audacity. The syslog entries that appear when I attempt to install GIMP this way can be downloaded from here: https://www.mediafire.com/file/8mib6t4wdty0dwk/gimp_install_syslog.txt/file

Answer (score 0):

These two problems are solved. For either of these apps to be able to do installations they have to be running with root privileges. I opened them in an account that was not root, and did not have root privileges.

Instead of opening them in the Application Launcher, I had to use these commands in the Konsole terminal emulator for their install functions to work:

sudo ubuntustudio-installer
sudo plasma-discover